# How to get more API records when the response size is limited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I don't have much experience with React or JavaScript. I am creating a simple application that fetches time series data from an API. The data is used to plot a line chart (React Apex Chart). All good.

The problem is that the API response size is limited to a maximum of 2,000 records, and sometimes we need more data.

#### The API documentation says:

*The response size is limited to a maximum of 2,000 records. If more records have to be returned, the response header contains a Link header with a URI to get the next set of records:*

Link: https://apiurl; rel="next"

#### My Fetch Code:

My code fetches the api data, sorts it and sends it to the child component(Chart).

```
  FetchAPI(){
    fetch(https://MYURLHERE?from=FROMDATE&to=TODATE)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ 
        kWhData: data.map((kWh) => kWh._kWh),
        TimeStampData: data.map((time) => time._time),
        loading: false
      }))
      .catch(error => console.log('Fetching failed', error))
  }
```

```
Link header: link →<https://MYURLHERE?from=FROMDATE&limit=2000&to=TODATE>; rel="next">
```

I know the solution may be some kind of pagination but I do not fully understand this concept. I have searched for similar problems with no luck.

Hope someone could provide me with a helping hand, tips or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I got it to work with a mix of both answers.

I do not know if this is a good way to do it or the "right" approach. Maybe you guys could give me some feedback?

The setTimeout was just for testing, but I think I need to have minimum 1000?

The credentials/header is necessary to get the API.

```
FetchAPI(requestURL) {
    fetch(requestURL, {
        credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "x-xsrf-token": this.myXRSFToken,
                "origin": `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`
            }
        })
    .then(response => {
        let Responseheader = response.headers.get('Link')
        response.json()
        .then(data => this.setState({
            TestData: this.state.TestData.concat(data)
        }))
        if (Responseheader){
            let nextPageUrl = Responseheader.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+Z/gi)
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.FetchAPI(nextPageUrl)
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            console.log('Done fetching API')
            this.setState({ 
                loading: false
            })
            return
          }  
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('Fetching failed', error))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what API you're using, but it sounds like all you need to do is get the URL to the next set of results from the headers and then make a request to that.

Before you return `response.json()`, you can access the headers with `response.headers.get()`. So you can do something like `let nextPage = response.headers.get('Link')` to get that full Link header as a string. Then you can split it at the semicolon and use the first part as the URL for the next paginated request.

Comment: Note that parsing the Link header is more complicated than just splitting on the semicolon.

Comment: Is it? Seems like `nextPage = nextPage.split(';'); nextPage.pop(); nextPage = nextPage.join(';')` should do the trick, based on the response mentioned in the question?

Comment: According to the OP, the Link header starts with the letters "link" then a tab character and an angle bracket. These aren't valid for a URL. (Also, why do you need to call `pop()` and `join()`?)

Comment: Maybe I misread; I thought that was just indicating that the Link header had the key name `link` and then the arrow was pointing to the value, which is the URL followed by `; rel="next"` . You could be right, it's a little unclear.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. If that interpretation is correct (which as you say is unclear), there are still the angle brackets to deal with. Regardless of these details, parsing the Link header is the correct way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood the question correctly, I would add a variable to your FetchApi function, so that it can query either your initial API URL, or the URL for a subsequent page:

```
FetchAPI(requestURL){
    // Fetch function here
}
```

The idea is that this function can then call itself iteratively, with the url of the ‘next’ page of results passed as a parameter for each call, until the response indicates all the data has been retrieved.

So your initial call would be FetchAPI('https://MYURLHERE?from=FROMDATE&to=TODATE').

You can then add a line to call this function again if the rate limit is reached. E.g:

```
FetchAPI(requestURL){
    fetch(requestURL)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.dataLimit == true){ // Or however this is expressed
                // Concat new data with any already retrieved
                this.FetchAPI(nextPageUrl) // Get the URL of the next page and call FetchAPI again with this e.g https://MYURLHERE?from=FROMDATE&limit=2000&to=TODATE
            } else {
                // Otherwise stop and do something else now that you have a complete set of data
            }
        })
}
```

Worth saying that this is untested code, but hopefully enough to get the principle across.

Also if the API has a request rate limit e.g. 1 second, you could add a delay before the function calls itself again, though obviously this will impact the overall time to retrieve all of the data.

Comment: Note that the docs says that the response will have the full URL for the next page of data. There is no reason to build this URL as you do here.

Comment: Comparing `== true` is redundant.

Comment: Technically yes, but its an example to illustrate the logic rather than the actual code to be used, and I think stating ==true adds clarity.

Comment: I have postet something that worked. A mix of both answers. Maybe you can take a look at it?

Comment: Good to hear you've got it working! The iterative aspect of the function looks fine to me. Has it successfully returned more than one page of results, and then stopped when they have all been retrieved?